# Package "com" contains directories which cannot be renamed

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Warring]

Trying to change the name of the packages, a warning comes out. I want to change the com.example.app to ru.example.app

Thanks

Comment: Unselect abbreviate qualified package names option from show option menu on left side panel, after which you will be able to see the package names separately. Rename the com directory from there then.

Answer (score 0):

1. simply create the new package on the project explorer.
2. select all the files and folders coming after the root package name from the package 1 (holding shift key on widows)
3. drop all those files to package 2

that's all. Android studio will do the rest of the refactoring for you.

**Note:** Before trying drag and drop for the whole files and folders, simply try just one file, and if you succeed, now you understood the trick and you are good to go as described above. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. try to click the button the one with red circle and disable the "**Compact Middle Packages**"
2. and you able to you will be able to view the package names separately.you will see the "**com directory**" - try to "**Shift + F6**" and click the "**Rename Current**" then cliked "**Refactor**".
3. the android studio will do the refactor all in project